# Интеграция верстки в WordPress?

Tags: html, wordpress, вёрстка, cms, интеграция

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть верстка сайта, одна главная страничка, и 2 внутренние. У внутренних разный HTML код, шапка немного другая, контент совсем другой. Как это интегрировать в WordPress?

Я пробовал код главной вставить в index.php, в пути к файлам добавил

```
<?php bloginfo("template_directory"); ?>/
```

все показывает. А для одной из внутренних сделал шаблон, файл clubfloor.php, перед HTML кодом прописал:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Шаблон страницы "Клубный этаж VIP залы"
*/
?>
```

Создал новую страницу в админке и применил ей этот шаблон, пути в шаблоне ко всем файлам приписал так же через , но при переходе на эту станицу в адресной строке, шаблон не применяется. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно все это реализовать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй использовать какую то базовую тему, не переполненную випсанными элементами, и какими то конструкторами... в таком раскладе в них проще разобраться.

[Вот](https://www.lyrathemes.com/bootstrap-wordpress-theme-tutorial-1/) неплохой гайд по созданию темы с нуля, в силу того что я в первую очередь верстальщик, мне было понятней делать именно так.

Еще есть вот [эта](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/21-best-wordpress-starter-themes-for-developers/) статья с подборкой базовых тем, но тут надо смотреть на твой функционал, который ты хочешь впиливать.

Еще полезным для такого подхода будет Shortcodes Pro, если не злоупотреблять